# Nginx redirect except some extensions

Tags: nginx, captiveportal

I wrote a script that configures a captive portal and everything is working fine. The problem I'm having is because nginx is redirecting all the requests to http://hotspot.localnet/index.php is also redirecting all requests for images. So none of the images in index.php work.

Is there a way to exclude png,pdf files from being redirected to index.php and be displayed? Tried many regex examples found on the internet but having no luck.

The source code of the nginx config file is here: https://github.com/tretos53/Captive-Portal/blob/master/default_nginx

This is access.log with the above configuration:

```
192.168.137.1 - - [03/Dec/2018:19:53:16 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 582 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
192.168.137.1 - - [03/Dec/2018:19:53:16 +0000] "GET /images/1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "http://hotspot.localnet/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
192.168.137.1 - - [03/Dec/2018:19:53:16 +0000] "GET /images/2.png HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "http://hotspot.localnet/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
192.168.137.1 - - [03/Dec/2018:19:53:16 +0000] "GET /images/3.png HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "http://hotspot.localnet/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
192.168.137.1 - - [03/Dec/2018:19:53:16 +0000] "GET /images/4.png HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "http://hotspot.localnet/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
192.168.137.1 - - [03/Dec/2018:19:53:16 +0000] "GET /images/5.png HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "http://hotspot.localnet/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
192.168.137.1 - - [03/Dec/2018:19:53:16 +0000] "GET /images/6.png HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "http://hotspot.localnet/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your config:

```
    location ~ \.(?:pdf|png)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, Does it matter where this statement is? Unfortunately this is still happening. 192.168.24.59 - - [04/Dec/2018:21:07:36 +0000] "GET /7.png HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "http://hotspot.localnet/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0;

Comment: Just checked your config on a real server. It works, but leads to infinite 302 redirection with pdf or png files. I updated my answer. The reason you still get redirection to index.php may be your browser cache, you can try to make a request from incognito window.

Comment: Yes, you are right I think it was my browser and it works now. I tried another solution from reddit and it worked too. Thanks for your help